# ImportError: No module named Mail python sendgrid

Tags: python, django

User.views.py
this is the folder of Mail/views.py im having error when i started the local development server

```
from Mail.views import sendgrid_mail

content['url'] = input_values["host"] + "/EmailVerification/" + 
user.email + '/' + md5_key
message = render_to_string('accountverification.html', content)
# sendMail.delay("[GavaGives] Account created successfully", message, 
content['email'])
sendgrid_mail('info', user.email, '[GavaGives] Account created 
successfully', message, 'user_offline_donation')

return response("create", "success", [])
```

Mail.views.py

```
def sendgrid_mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content, template):
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient(config('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
mail = sendgrid.Mail()

mail.add_to(to_email)
mail.set_from(mail_from(from_email))
mail.set_subject(subject)
mail.set_html(content)

mail.add_filter('templates', 'enable', '1')
mail.add_filter('templates', 'template_id', get_templates(template))

sg.send(mail)
```

Settings.py 
this is the folder of the main project/settings.py im having error when i started the local development server

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.sessions',
'corsheaders',  # CORS installation
'django_cron',  # celery
'django_crontab',  # Cron jobs
'celery',
'djcelery',
'Users',
'Campaign',
'Donor',
'Media',
'Admin',
'Common',
'CommonModules',
'Event',
'Cards',
'Mail'
]
```

this my project Folder Structure base on django. any help would be much appreciated. thanks

```
<pre>
[projectname]/
├── [admin]/
├── campaign/
├── card/
├── common/
├── commonmodules/
├── donor/
├── event/
├── gavagives/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── cel.py
│       ├── cronjobs.py
│       ├── custom_commands.py
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       ├── views.py
│       ├── wsgi.py
├── logs/
├── Mail/
│       ├── mail.py
│       ├── views.py
├── node_modules/
├── manage.py
├── README.rst
├── requirements.txt
├── .env
├── Users/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── cronjobs.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       ├── validations.py
│       ├── views.py
├── venv/
│       ├── include
│       ├── Lib
│       ├── Scripts
│       ├── tcl
├── License.txt 
├── .gitignore
</pre>
```

Comment: what is your folder structure of the project

Comment: do you have `__init__.py` inside `Mail`? Have you created `Mail` as django-app or its just a package?

Comment: my Mail folder contains: mail.py  and  views.py. No its a django-app

Comment: create an empty `__init__.py` file inside the Mail folder so that python recognizes it as a module.

Comment: creating __init__.py solved the issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per [**`django documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#module-django.apps), an app must contain [**`models`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/) to be treated as a django app. Basically here you are creating a [**`package`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), so you don't need to include it in `INSTALLED_APPS`. To allow other apps/packages/modules in your project to use your files inside the `Mail` folder, you need to create an `__init__.py` file inside that folder. Without having a `__init__.py` file inside the folder, Python will no longer look for submodules inside that directory, so attempts to import the module will fail. More information can be found in [**`python documentation`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages) regarding how to import from regular package.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import mail python send grid by using  **pip**.

you enter this line in juper note book or command.

```
pip install mail python sendgrid
```

or

```
 pip3 install mail python sendgrid
```